# Discount to cart if specific product is in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, price-rules

I'm searching about three days for solution now, and i just can't find a way to solve this.

My Scenario:

At 299$ Subtotal I want to give the customer the option to choose from:
1. a free product or 
2. a cart discount

The first part of this could be done easily with a plugin -> choose a free product when subtotal is 299$. So i have planed to do the discount as a product, that you can add to cart.

So you have a product called "5% off" and if you add this to cart, you will get 5% off from the whole cart.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup a cart rule up for either the amount or if you really want to use a product you can setup the rule based on the sku of the product

Comment: Thank you for the reply, appreciate that! The way with the product (discount as prdouct) is the only solution atm i can imagine, to make it possible that the customer can choose between a free product or the discount (by adding the discount product to cart). I think it's not possible to make a rule that says: if product x (by sku) is in cart, give 5% discount to the whole cart, or am i wrong?

Comment: If you create a new attribute set and assign the free products to it you should be able to execute your shopping cart rules by attribute set and cart total